# Cериализация / десериализация DataContractSerializer. Object to byte[] / byte [] to object

Tags: c#, uwp

Задача написать класс с методами, который будет выполнять сериализацию, десериализацию любого объекта в массив байт и обратно.
Я написал сериализацию (не уверен, что это правильно)

```
static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj) where T : class
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                DataContractSerializer ser =
                    new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
                ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Пример есть, например, [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb675198.aspx), но там используют xml файл, а мне нужно без него. Как написать сериализацию/десериализацию без фала?
Получу ли я байты объекта из потока?

Comment: Так-то оно работать будет, да. Получить обратно данные вполне получится. Однако, `DataContractSerializer` сериализует в xml, который потом пишется в поток. Если нужен именно массив байтов, то лучше, вероятно, использовать бинарную сериализацию. Например, `BinaryFormatter`.

Comment: Прошу обратить внимание на тег UWP. BinaryFormatter нет в .NetCore.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : class
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Position = 0;
        DataContractSerializer deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        return deserializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
    }
}
```

Comment: Методы получились несимметричные. Надо в первом все-таки `typeof(T)` использовать, а не `obj.GetType()`.

Comment: Кстати, зачем записывать массив в поток, если можно обернуть поток над массивом?..

Comment: Ну и для `MemoryStream` `using` не требуется - ведь он не содержит ресурсов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот более простой вариант:

```
public static byte[] Serialize<T>(T obj) where T : class
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, obj);
    return stream.ToArray();
}

public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : class
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream(data);
    var deserializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
    return deserializer.ReadObject(stream) as T;
}
```